# How to Prevent/Disable History Stack in React Router

Tags: ios, react-router-dom, mobile-safari

Is there anyway to disable BrowserRouter or History from React Router? I do not want my browser to know I went to a different page.

Comment: The browser toolbar is part of the browser and has absolutely nothing to do with your React app. You can't control it, iOS/Safari does. How are you routing/navigating around the app? Please update your post to include a relevant [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese In Safari, the Toolbar appears when the user navigates to a different page. React Router pushes history onto the browser window. I have accomplished this before using vanilla JS, but with React Router I cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The `MemoryRouter` does not push to the Browser, so the back button and forward button won't appear.

Source:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter